# How to solve "Unable to find an entry point named 'Z3_enable_concurrent_dec_ref'"

Tags: z3

I tried to use dotnet Z3 **v4.12.2**, and got:

> "Unhandled exception. System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'Z3_enable_concurrent_dec_ref' in shared library 'libz3'".

But dotnet Z3 with versions 4.11.2 and earlier are working.

I tried to use .nupkg for Z3 `v4.12.2` but got same problem.